# Two semantic sidebars in "layers" on a page?

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

**Environment: Electron desktop single page app**

I have a project where I would like to use two `Semantic UI` sidebars schemes. Only one scheme will be visible at a time. I've seen this earlier question (
[Semantic-UI: Two Sidebars Conflict, Only One at a Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063542/semantic-ui-two-sidebars-conflict-only-one-at-a-time) ) but it only partly answers my question.

Doing a simple test, wrapping each sidebar scheme in a `div`, I've had some `Semantic UI` warnings ( *"Had to move sidebar. For optimal performance make sure sidebar and pusher are direct children of your body tag"*). Before I go further, can anyone tell me if the structure below will work or if there is some other recommended way to go about this?

I will show/hide these "layers" based on user interaction – both layers need the Semantic sidebar feature.

---

```
  <body>
  <div id="LAYER-1" class="ui sidebar inverted vertical menu">
    <!-- ************** Sidebar content ************* !-->
  </div>    
  <div class="pusher">
    <!-- ************** Layer content ************* !-->
  </div>

  <div id="LAYER-2" class="ui sidebar inverted vertical menu">
    <!-- ************** Sidebar content ************* !-->
  </div>    
  <div class="pusher">
    <!-- ************** Layer content ************* !-->
  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this through setting the `context` for the `Semantic` sidebar. This answer ([Semantic-ui - how to use sidebar in only part of a page? (ie with context)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664906/semantic-ui-how-to-use-sidebar-in-only-part-of-a-page-ie-with-context)) helped to clarify how to specify the `context` somewhat better than the [example](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/examples) in the `Semantic` docs

So what I've ended up with: wrap each "sidebar set" in a div with an ID and then specify that div as the `context`. The "layer" divs have buttons to show/hide the top-most layer. Not getting any `Semantic` warnings about the set up.

---

JS

```
$('#briefcaseExample .ui.sidebar')
        .sidebar({
            context: $('#briefcaseExample')
        })
        .sidebar('setting', 'transition', 'push')


$('#timelineExample .ui.sidebar')
        .sidebar({
            context: $('#timelineExample')
        })
        .sidebar('setting', 'transition', 'push')
```

---

HTML

```
<body onload="onLoadApp()">

    <div id="briefcaseExample">
        <div class="ui sidebar inverted vertical menu">
            <!-- ************** Sidebar content ************* !-->
            <div id="sidebarTree" style="height: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- ************** End Sidebar content ************* !-->

        <div class="pusher">
            <!-- ************** Site content ************* !-->
            <div id="solidBlue"></div>
            <div id="container" width="100%" height="100%">
                <canvas id="c" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
            </div>

            <div class="briefcaseSidebarToggle">
                <i class="big sidebar icon grey" onclick="toggleMenu()"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="briefcaseClose">
                <i class="big remove circle icon grey" onclick="hideBriefcase()"></i>
            </div>
            <!-- ************** End Site content ************* !-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="timelineExample">
        <div class="ui sidebar inverted vertical menu">
            <!-- ************** Sidebar content ************* !-->
            <div id="timelineSidebar" style="height: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- ************** End Sidebar content ************* !-->

        <div class="pusher">
            <!-- ************** Site content ************* !-->
            <div class="timelineSidebarToggle">
                <i class="big sidebar icon grey" onclick="toggleTimelineMenu()"></i>
            </div>

            <!-- ************** End Site content ************* !-->

            <div id="solidColor">
                <button onclick="showBriefcase()">Show Briefcase</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```